# Zend - undefined class TableGateway

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

When I copy from documentation:

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
```

php storm shows

undefined class TableGateway.

What can be wrong?

I tried to search in whole project "TableGateway" and I did not find that classname.

I tried run command again

```
 composer install
```

in case something went wrong, but it shows everything is installed. The composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer": "^1.0 || ^0.3 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "^3.0.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "^3.0",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "extra": [],
    "scripts": {
        "cs-check": "phpcs",
        "cs-fix": "phpcbf",
        "development-disable": "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable": "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status": "zf-development-mode status",
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@development-enable"
        ],
        "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php",
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the DB component if you want to use classes from it:

```
composer require zendframework/zend-db
```

Comment: Btw after running composer require ... I did not need to run composer install if I udnerstand well, it installed it also.